# Can't subscribe rhel 8.5 VM to subscription manager

Tags: subscription

All. I recently built a RHEL 8.5 (Ootpa) VM with all the bells and whistles in my home lab. II want to run yum update -y to see if there's a link between 8.6 and 8.5 not subscribing. Below is a copy of the output on my server:

[~]$ sudo subscription-manager attach --auto
Installed Product Current Status:
Product Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux for x86_64
Status:       Not Subscribed

Unable to find available subscriptions for all your installed products.
[erik@RHEL85-1 ~]$ sudo subscription-manager list
+-------------------------------------------+
Installed Product Status
+-------------------------------------------+
Product Name:   Red Hat Enterprise Linux for x86_64
Product ID:     479
Version:        8.5
Arch:           x86_64
Status:         Not Subscribed
Status Details: Not supported by a valid subscription.
Starts:
Ends:

[~]$ sudo yum repolist
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
repo id                                 repo name
packages-microsoft-com-prod             packages-microsoft-com-prod
[~]$

Comment: This site is for programming related questions only. You can find more information about this site in the [help]. You're looking for [unix.se] instead.

Comment: Thank you, Ken. Will do!